# The most efficient way to compare two large txt files

Tags: string, file, go

I have two txt files:

**File1:** Contains 500.000.000 lines

**File2:** Contains 10.000 lines

I want to iterate through each line of `File1` and check if it contains the corresponding line of `File2`. The most basic way to do is creating two `for` loops. Such as:

```
for i in file2:
 for y in file1:
   if y contains i:
     save i to file3
```

What is the fastest and the most efficient way to do it in Go?

Answer (score 4):

Read `File2` into memory, and build a set of the lines. For a set in Go, use a `map[string]bool` or `map[string]struct{}`.

Then open `File1`, read line-by-line, and check each line if it is contained in the set (map). If it is in the set, save it to `File3`.

Comment: If the line length becomes prohibitive long: Use hashes of the line as map keys and compare full line only for the matches (probably in a second step).

Comment: @Volker Although this seems like a good suggestion at first, it's probably redundant. This is what the hashmap implementation internally does: hashes the key and checks the bucket designated by the hash. Then tries to compare the key with the values in the bucket, very similar to what your suggestion would do. Comparing the values (strings) is efficient as it first just checks the length, and if that matches, then tries to compare the bytes until a difference is found.

Comment: In reagard to performance: Yes. But not in regard to memory: A Go map has to store all its keys. If each of the 5e8 keys is 2e4 bytes long the memory needed to store the keys is 100GByte. Hashing the keys to 256bit reduces that that to 0.2 GB.

Comment: @Volker But I would put the lines of the smaller files into the set, which is only 10.000, not 5e8.

Comment: True, but the line length of the smaller one might be 1e8 bytes. (But I admit that's unlikely).